# Making a simple clockin/clockout site. Second button doesn't complete the task assigned

Tags: javascript, html

[JsFiddle of issue](http://jsfiddle.net/ADWKp/1/)

I have two functions within the script, one for the Clock In time, and the second for when you clock out, which also computes the total time.  I haven't yet added in the actual calculation for finding the total time, that is not the issue.  No code will run in the second function after the line `var hoursTwo = currentTime.getHours();`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your `getDateTwo()` function does not have access to the `currentTime` variable because it is not declared inside of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to call an undeclared var

```
var hoursTwo = currentTime.getHours()
```

is supposed to call

```
var hoursTwo = currentTimeTwo.getHours()
```

and so on for each function. If you want to access `currentTime` you should declare it outside a function.

Just FYI, using developer tools or firebug can reveal a lot in console. This reported the error in plain english.